# How to specify the location when creating a Bigquery dataset in Java

Tags: google-bigquery

How do I specify the location when creating a Bigquery dataset in Java?

I want to create it in the Tokyo(asia-northeast1) region.

Perhaps the official guide doesn't explain how to specify the location.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the documentation could help you

First you can find an exemple of a basic dataset creation :
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#java

Then you can fit it to your needs, with the given set location method from the dataset builder :
https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/com/google/cloud/bigquery/DatasetInfo.Builder.html#setLocation-java.lang.String-